# Один и тот же ответ от сервера

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование

Добрый день, есть кнопка, при нажатии на эту кнопку отправляется запрос на сервер с токеном(токен передается в header) и возвращает количество разрешенных попыток нажатия на кнопку(всего на кнопку можно нажать 5 раз)

```
{
  "result": "ok",
  "access_token": "rsNQgkedqLcapou9yLSFIy_JRE0D0-enl0T4b-t9EJoFSagYsBzlq2xPRmlsRZW2zfjwYgo4WAPJdGlzNZw5RvKJDMfcX3fQIvbKY8SC3KV2bXdvpRH-aqbNAeyRecJy"
}
```

. Далее после того как он вернул количество попыток открывается новая активность , а там еще кнопка, при нажатии на нее отправляется запрос где в header передается `token`  и `vin`.

Привожу код:

```
@GET("/vin/autoru/{vin}")
Call<VinInfo> getVinData(@Path("vin") String vin,@Header("Authorization") String  token);


@OnClick(R.id.bank_button_vinCheckActivity)
public void getPledgeData() {
    if (isConnected() && mVinLength != 12) {
        showDialog(getString(R.string.loading_data), this);
        mServerApi.getVinData(mVinCode,mToken).enqueue(new Callback<VinInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VinInfo> call, Response<VinInfo> response) {
                Log.d("mdaq",response.body().toString());
                Log.d("MyEnglish", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                if (response.body() != null)
                    if (response.body().getMarks() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getMarks().size() > 0) {
                            showModelsDialog(response.body().getMarks());
                            hideDialog();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (response.body().getPledge().equals("1")) {
                            getBankInfo();
                        } else {
                            hideDialog();
                            makeInfoDialog(getString(R.string.no_bank), true);
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Передача токена должна быть след.вида : Header

```
Authorization: Bearer rsNQgkedqLcapou9yLSFIy_JRE0D0-enl0T4b-t9EJoFSagYsBzlq2xPRmlsRZW2zfjwYgo4WAPJdGlzNZw5RvKJDMfcX3fQIvbKY8SC3KV2bXdvpRH-aqbNAeyRecJy
```

У меня в коде так :

```
mToken = "Bearer " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("token");
```

В этом запросе передается токен и vin на сервер. Сервер должен после этого запрос уменьшать count на 1 и при следующем нажатии на кнопку из 1 активности, вернуть мне 4, а не 5 попыток.

А он возвращает мне всегда 5;

Почему мне всегда возвращается 5 ?

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не минусовать всякий раз -1 ? Наверное глупо... :) первое что пришло в голову

Comment: @Денис отличный костыль, но он действует только временно)
При переустановке приложения я опять смогу спокойно слать запросы)